# Python and nesting classes for structure

Tags: python, class, inheritance, nested

I am having a bit of trouble with nesting classes in python.

Mind you my code below is a simplified example showing what I want to do, but basically I want to use nested classes to make my code more structured and make sure I don't run into name clashes for certain functions.

See here my example code:

```
class Chrome:

    def __init__(self, url='http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'):

        # Capabilities
        capabilities    = Capabilities.chrome()

        # Start session
        self.driver     = webdriver.Remote(url, capabilities)


    def get_url(self, url):

        # Go to URL
        self.driver.get(url)


    class actions:

        @staticmethod
        def browse_url(url):

            # Go to url
            Chrome.get_url(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    browser = Chrome()

    browser.actions.browse_url('https://www.google.com')
```

The goal as you can see in `if __name__ == '__main__'` is to be able to start a browser instance, and then call functions in a structured way.

However I have no clue on how to correctly achieve the `browser.actions.browse_url('https://www.google.com')` concept.

How is this done correctly ?

Comment: What problem are you having? Error message? If so, what? Unexpected result? What are they?

Comment: @kindall error: `TypeError: unbound method get_url() must be called with Chrome instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `get_url` from an instance of `Chrome` and not the class itself, since it's an instance method and not a static one:

```
...
@staticmethod
def browse_url(url):
     Chrome().get_url(url) 
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Chrome.actions.browse_url('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new instance every time? That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Snowlav Yes it would. Except you make it a static method, and then you'll have to figure another way to set up  a `driver` for the class that is accessible by `get_url`

Comment: home can I share the same instance for every function then? I thought that's why I called `browser = Chrome()` at the start. I could say `browser.get_url(url)` in the function however that requires users to always use the variable `browser` to create the instance

Comment: Keep in mind that the `action` class is nested in the `Chrome` class and `browse_url` is static, so this makes it a little more complicated than you think

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all.

Comment: All I want to do is to be able to call `class_instance.nested_class.function`

Comment: I showed you one way to do that. Any other way would require you either instantiate action or Chrome at some point in your program

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127966/discussion-between-snowlav-and-moses-koledoye).